# How can I keep my resizing animation (javascript) from messing up my (css) "float" layout?

Tags: javascript, html, css, layout, css-float

I made a layout in css using floats:

```
.thumb{
  border-radius:20px;
  border: RGB(245, 245, 220);
  border-width: 10px;
  border-style:solid;
  float:left;
  margin:20px;
  padding:0px
}
```

Then I wrote some javascript to make the images expand with mouse-overs.

```
$(".thumb img").mouseover(function() {
$(this).animate({'width':204, 'height':252}, {duration:300});
                    }).mouseout(function(){

$(this).animate({'width':195, 'height':240}, {duration:100});
                    });
```

I suppose I should have anticipated that this would mess up the layout - when ever you scroll over an image, the next row moves down a row - is there a way to fix this?

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yshore/e3jwy17h/)

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle with your problem?

Comment: You could use `transform: scale` for a similar effect.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=jF02SLhz0k

Comment: Thanks @gcampbell!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your image elements in a .thumb absolutes and make .thumb elements relative. Make your .thumb elements absolute and it should do the trick.
Roughly it should look like this:

```
.thumb{
  border-radius:20px;
  border: RGB(245, 245, 220);
  border-width: 10px;
  border-style:solid;
  float:left;
  margin:20px;
  padding:0px;
  position: relative;
}

.thumb img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```